# How to render HTML text with JavaScript embedded with C# only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, razor

In my current project, I have used RazorEngine to render an HTML template to an HTML string (Filled in some data). The next step is save this page as PDF file. However, in the HTML code, there are some JavaScript code embedded in the HTML string (which is used to generate barcode). If I directly save the HTML string to PDF file, the JavaScript will not be execute to render it's part.

The problem is, how to get the JavaScript rendered HTML code?

```
Private String GetJsRenderedHtml (string htmlStr){
    // Execute JS code in htmlStr to render the html
    // Return rendered code.
}
```

Comment: Just call the function from your html when the Dom is ready and save it in a variable

Comment: this may need to use some external libraries as razor renders pages on server side while js is being run on browser side. this will cause you to "emulate" browser on server side which is not "as simple as it may sound".